# How to update Zend Server Community?

Tags: lubuntu, webserver, zend

I have Ubuntu 11.10 and zend-server 5.3.8-ZS5.5.0.

So I would like to update it time by time. But I don't even know which packages it uses. If I do

> apt-get update

it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-get update` updates your whole system (if that software is part of any repository that is). Not just zend server.

From the [zend server](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/deb_installation.htm) website:

> Upgrading Zend Server
>
> Upgrading Zend Server can be performed using the following programs:
>
> 'aptitude'
>      'apt-get'
>
> To perform this action you must have root privileges.

It means that the update of this bit of software is done by `update manager`. If there is no update `apt-get` will not show any results.

Package name seems to be `zend-server-php-x.y` where `x.y` is the PHP version. You can check your repository since there should be a line included for this installation:

```
deb http://repos.zend.com/zend-server/deb server non-free
```

All the packages inside this repository belong to zend server and `apt-get update` will check these for newer versions.

Comment: Thx a lot! I've read it but didn't understand exactly what I should do. Now it's ok. It updated successful.